# Threejs Raycast Intersects empty with scene.children. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Post 1) I am trying to detect all objects viewable by the camera so I can reposition them to the starting position once they are out of view. I am aiming for an infinite waterfall effect that reuses the existing objects. I really don't why intersects is empty and it works if I raycast for individual objects while looping through scene.children but this will lead to very bad performance because it is in the animation loop.

Thanks for any help

Post 2) I have changed over to frustrum culling but frustum.containsPoint(scene.children[index]) always returns true even when objects are clearly out of camera view.

Again any help is appreciated

```js
camera.updateMatrix();
  camera.updateMatrixWorld();

  var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
  var projScreenMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  projScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse);

  // frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(camera.projectionMatrix);
  frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse));

  for (let index = 0; index < scene.children.length; index++) {
    scene.children[index].updateMatrix(); // make sure plane's local matrix is updated
    scene.children[index].updateMatrixWorld();

    if (frustum.containsPoint(scene.children[index])) {
      //stuff happens...
      if (scene.children[index].name === "coin") {
        scene.children[index].rotation.x += 0.01;
        scene.children[index].position.y -= 0.1;
      }
      // console.log("mesh in view Frustrum");
    } else {
      console.log("mesh not in view Frustrum");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to detect all objects viewable by the camera

You don't need raycasting for this. Instead, setup an instance of [Frustum](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Frustum) based on the projection and view matrix of your camera via `setFromProjectionMatrix()`. In the next step, use `intersectsObject()` to detect whether a 3D object is inside the camera's view frustum (the viewable area of the 3D scene) or not.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have change my code and edited the post to reflect the changes but intersectsObject is always returning true